# Create an nginx reverse proxy container to forward to specific URL/Port based on requested URL

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy

I want to setup an nginx reverse proxy docker container which forwards based on the URL requested. I have setup dns pointing from all these subdomains of domain.com to the nginx server container.

Example scenario:

Request: subdomain1.domain.com
should forward to abc.xyz.com:8087

Request: subdomain2.domain.com
should forward to abc.xyz.com:8088

I need to know what I should write in the dockerfile and the nginx.conf file to make the above forward happen. Also these forwards will grow in the future, would there be a way to add these programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Dockerfile

(I had to do the SSL termination, so here you will find SSL related files too, just ignore those if it is not applicable for you.)

```
FROM nginx:alpine
#create the server and location configuration
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY cert.pem /etc/nginx-certs/cert.pem
COPY key.pem /etc/nginx-certs/key.pem
COPY ssl.pass /etc/nginx-certs/ssl.pass
RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx-logs/
```

### nginx.conf

This nginx is configured to reverse proxy any request coming to http**s**:// to http://:8080

```
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx-certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx-certs/key.pem;
    ssl_password_file         /etc/nginx-certs/ssl.pass;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    access_log            /etc/nginx-logs/<MYAPPLICATION NAME>.access.log;
    client_body_in_file_only on;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://<MYIPADDRESS>:8080/;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://<MYIPADDRESS>:8080 https://localhost;
    }
  }
```

**Please Note**, We had a very primal need, so this setup did the trick for us. Just take this as a starting point. Don't refer this example for nginx best practices and such.

For your particular need like

> Request: subdomain1.domain.com should forward to abc.xyz.com:8087
>
> Request: subdomain2.domain.com should forward to abc.xyz.com:8088

you can customize nginx.conf further, you can add more locations for different routes . Here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms Digital Ocean did a nice job in documenting basics of nginx.

And, to manage, nginx.conf, I wouldn't automate the configuration, I would just add it to a version control system like git and set up a CI-CD system like drone.io or travis to manage the deployment. Again, that's just me, you might be having totally different need.

### If you want to redirect all http calls to https

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: What if i need to add multiple forwards as mentioned in the question? Which part do I change?

Comment: you can add more locations. Here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms Digital Ocean did a nice job in documenting basics of nginx

Answer (score 1):

Below is the simplest form of nginx.conf file for request

- subdomain1.domain.com should forward to abc.xyz.com:8087
- subdomain2.domain.com should forward to abc.xyz.com:8088

---

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    
    server_name subdomain1.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://abc.xyz.com:8087/;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name subdomain2.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://abc.xyz.com:8087/;
    }
}
```